# method not working when i call it from another method for random name gen in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I am creating a random name generator using OOP in python however i am very new to this concept which is why i am having so difficulties with accessing methods in other methods. I read a post on stack overflow which said to call a method inside another method in a class, you must add self.funcname(param) however i have already done this and it still does not work

```
class Rndm_nme_gen:
    def __init__(self):
        print("THE RANDOM NAME GENERATOR")
        self.value = ""
        self.range = 5
        self.counter = 0
        self.loop = True
        self.names = []
        self.loop2 = True
        self.take_input()

    def take_input(self):
        while self.loop:
            user_input = input("ENTER A NAME: ")
            self.num_check(user_input)
            if self.value == "true":
                print("INVALID NAME")
                loop = True
            elif self.value == "false":
                self.counter += 1
                self.names.append(user_input)
                if self.counter == 5:
                    self.loop = False
        self.genname()
        #i am trying to call this function but it is not working as i hoped it would


    def num_check(self, string):
        self.string = string
        for char in self.string:
            if char.isdigit():
                self.value = "true"
            else:
                self.value = "false"

    def genname(self):
        while self.loop:
            gen = input("TYPE ENTER TO GENERATE A NAME OR TYPE 'q' TO QUIT").strip().lower()
            if gen == " " or gen == "":
                num = random.randint(0, 5)
                print("NAME : " + str(self.names[num]))
                loop == True
            elif gen == 'q':
                quit()

            else:
                print("UNKNOWN COMMAND")
                loop = True


user1 = Rndm_nme_gen()
```

In the initialisation method, i called the take_input function so it automatically runs and from that function, i attempted to run the code from the genname function however the program would simply end
If you would like to run the code to see how it works, feel free to do so

Expected output:

```
ENTER NAME FDSF
ENTER NAME  dfsd
ENTER NAME  sdfds
ENTER NAME  sfdff
ENTER NAME sfdf
TYPE ENTER TO GENERATE A NAME OR TYPE 'q' TO QUIT
```

it does not say TYPE ENTER TO GENERATE A NAME OR TYPE 'q' TO QUIT when i run the program

Comment: Think carefully: what is the value of `self.loop` at the point that you call `self.genname`? (Hint: is the loop inside `take_input` still running?) Now, what is the condition under which the loop inside `self.genname` executes?

Comment: It seems that your question is not really about OOP or classes at all; you would have fundamentally the same problems trying to use ordinary functions. You should study more fundamentals first. For example, are you familiar with the `break` keyword?

Comment: whoops my mistake, accidentally used self.loop in the genname function when i created another variable for the genname function self.loop2.